# Is Amazon SimpleDB more reliable/available than DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb, amazon-dynamodb

This question is **not about a general comparison** between the two but more specifically focussed on high availability and reliability. From amazon's documentation about this:

> SimpleDB
>
> > Amazon SimpleDB automatically creates multiple geographically distributed copies of each data item you store. This provides high availability and durability – in the unlikely event that one replica fails, Amazon SimpleDB can failover to another replica in the system.

and

> DynamoDB
>
> > Amazon DynamoDB is a fully managed NoSQL database service that provides fast and predictable performance with seamless scalability. 
> >     The service runs across Amazon’s proven, high-availability data centers. The service replicates data across multiple facilities in an AWS Region to provide fault tolerance in the event of a server failure or Availability Zone outage.

So, in relative terms, is one more reliable than the other?

Answer (score 5):

Both services are highly available and reliable. The main difference being performance and cost.

SimpleDB is a NoSQL database as well is DynamoDB, DynamoDB however is designed for single digit millisecond fast performance under any amount of load. SimpleDB is also going to be fast but its not designed for large datasets.

As a result billing for DynamoDB is much more expensive. You must also "reserve" usage for dynamoDB its not billing you on how many requests you make, its billing you on how many you think you're going to make.

DynamoDB - Large datasets and fast performance

SimpleDB - Small / Medium datasets and cheaper

Comment: Thanks but, like I mentioned, the question is not about a general comparison but only about reliability. I realize that both are _highly_ available and reliable The question is specifically if, **in relative terms**, one is better than the other?

To illustrate a point in case, SimpleDB was [not affected by the April 2011 outage](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011_04_01_archive.html).

Comment: The two services are both as reliable. The outage amazon had in April 2011 could happen to any service at any time. Even systems designed for failure can still break. We're all human we all make mistakes. The chance of it happening is very low, but it can still happen.